# How do I use Count in a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, count

I'm having trouble using count in a subquery. I want to write a query that will return the number of comments per consumer, but count is giving me the total number of comments that exist.

```
SELECT con.Consumer_ID, con.Scheduled, con.Been_Called, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Comments WHERE com.ConsumerID = con.Consumer_ID) AS NumComments
FROM Consumers con
INNER JOIN Comments com
ON con.Consumer_ID = com.ConsumerID
```

I'm trying to get the number of comments per user, but instead NumComments is giving me the total number of comments that exists in the Comments table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause in the subquery is incorrect:

```
SELECT con.Consumer_ID, con.Scheduled, con.Been_Called, 
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM Comments c WHERE c.ConsumerID = con.Consumer_ID
) AS NumComments
FROM Consumers con
```

Now it only counts comments with matching consumer_id

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are overcomplicating this. A simple aggregated join might do the trick, like :

```
SELECT con.Consumer_ID, con.Scheduled, con.Been_Called, COUNT(*) as NumComments
FROM Consumers con
INNER JOIN Comments com ON com.Consumer_ID = con.ConsumerID
GROUP BY con.Consumer_ID, con.Scheduled, con.Been_Called
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT con.Consumer_ID, con.Scheduled, con.Been_Called, COUNT(DISTINCT com.CommentID) AS NumComments
FROM Consumers con
INNER JOIN Comments com
ON con.Consumer_ID = com.ConsumerID
GROUP BY con.Consumer_ID, con.Scheduled, con.Been_Called
```